# How to set an Alias in AVA tests

Tags: javascript, npm, alias, package.json, ava

I'm trying to set alias globally in my project without using Webpack, Babel, etc. Right now I have a simple test with [AVA](https://github.com/avajs/ava).

I'm using [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) npm package that let me set in package.json my aliases. However, when I try to just create a simple example following the documentation with a basic **alias** it doesn't find the file:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@root/my-module.js'
```

You can reproduce this example with these 3 files:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ava-alias",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ava"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ava": "^2.4.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "ava": {
    "require": [
      "esm",
      "module-alias"
    ]
  },
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@root": "."
  }
}
```

**test.js**

```
require('module-alias/register')

import test from 'ava'
//import cube from './my-module.js'  // working
import cube from '@root/my-module.js' // not working

test('cube of 3 is 27', t => {
    t.is(cube(3), 27)
})
```

**my-module.js**

```
export default function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x
}
```

Save these files to an empty folder and then in that path in your terminal: `npm i && npm run test`

Maybe I'm missing same basics, thank you so much for time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue.
You can solve this by using `module-alias/register` inside your Ava config.

Your **package.json** should look like:

```
{
  "name": "ava-alias",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ava"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ava": "^2.4.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "ava": {
    "require": [
      "esm",
      "module-alias/register"
    ]
  },
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@root": "."
  }
}
```